# Pandas Dataframe Transpose to varying number of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to transpose something like:

```
    ID    name
1     1    name
2     1    name1
3     2    name2
4     2    name3
5     2    name4
```

Into something like:

```
     ID    col1  col2  col3
1     1    name  name1 Null
2     2    name2 name3 name4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following, create a column variable firstly, then use `pivot`:

```
df['col'] = 'col' + (df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
df.pivot('ID', 'col', 'name')

#col    col1     col2    col3
#ID         
#1      name    name1    None
#2     name2    name3   name4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot table :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,2,2], 'name': 'name','name1','name2','name3','name4']})
df['No.'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df.pivot(index='ID', columns='No.', values='name')
```

return:

```
No. 0   1   2
ID          
1   name    name1   None
2   name2   name3   name4
```

or `.unstack()`:

```
df.set_index(['ID','No.'])['name'].unstack('No.')
```

return:

```
No. 0   1   2
ID          
1   name    name1   None
2   name2   name3   name4
```